# UTC and offset date time compare in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am storing UTC datetime in Database

e.g.

> 2018-06-05 11:37:00.000 (UTC)
>
> 2018-06-05 17:07 (+5:30 India standart time)

I am having offset as :

> offset as +02:00

How can I compare in sql query that now offset time matched ?

e.g.

> 2018-06-05 13:37:00.000

My issue is X (IST) date time converted to UTC and now I want to covert to different time zone (Y)

Comment: New support for TZ features such as AT TIME ZONE have only been introduced most recently in 2016. Generally, it is a good idea to keep TZ logic in your application layer and just store dates in UTC. If your transactions are specific to a location or user then you will need to know that TZ for the conversion. The problem with just applying a 2 hour offset is the varying timing of DST, if the TZ adheres to it. You would have to keep record of which time zone adheres to DST and when that adherence starts and ends. It gets uglier because the DST schedules change over time as well as the offsets.

Comment: My issue is X (IST) date time converted to UTC and now I want to covert to different time zone (Y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following functions helped me to resolve the issue:

> **1. SWITCHOFFSET**
>
> **2. TODATETIMEOFFSET**

```
SELECT GETDATE()
SELECT SWITCHOFFSET(GETDATE(), '+05:30')  
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), SWITCHOFFSET(TODATETIMEOFFSET(GETDATE(), '+05:30'),'+00:00'), 120)
SELECT GETUTCDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use the DATEADD function to calculate the new datetime based on the UTC datetime and the offset

For example:

2 hours = 120 minutes

```
DATEADD(minute, 120, '2018-06-05 11:37:00.000')
```

Or using hours

```
DATEADD(hour, 2, '2018-06-05 11:37:00.000')
```

You can also go the other way using negative numbers

You don't have to use a literal value, you can supply a column name to parameter 3 for use in a query and also use this expression as part of a where clause

---

Here's a cheat sheet for the DATEADD function:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: My issue is X (IST) date time converted to UTC and now I want to covert to different time zone (Y)

Comment: You can still use the DATEADD function to work out these differences. If you're storing the value as UTC, to convert to another timezone you simply add or subtract the distance of that timezone to/from UTC. So for IST (+05:30, or 330 minutes), you'd use DATEADD(minutes, 330, UTCDateColumn)